# DateJS parse datetime issue

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, datetime, datejs

I'm currently have the datetime format like this:

```
2012-10-11T00:00:00Z
```

and it looks like datejs is not happy with the trailing 'z'.

in the request, i just use

```
"\/Date(" + new Date(2012-10-11T00:00:00).getTime() + ")\/";
```

to make it as a json required format, but when it comes back from the response(c# backend), 'z' is automatically added. Is there any way to get rid of it or make the datejs be able to parse this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Checkout [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), It has solved many common issues regarding datetime in javascript.

> A 5kb javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.

Comment: *All* issues regarding datetime? Does it allow you to find out the client time zone (not just the current offset from UTC)? If so, that's great... but if not, it clearly doesn't meet your claim. That's not to say it's a bad thing, just not worthy of such hyperbole.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have found it in there website "By default, moment parses in local time. If you want to parse a moment in UTC, you can use the following methods", I think it solves the client time zone issue.

Comment: @Asif—it would be handy if authors of such libraries made them compliant the ECMA-262. The default for an ISO extended format [date time string](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) with no timezone is UTC, not local.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your date time string is always in that format, and is always UTC, you can convert it very easily to a date object using [Date.UTC](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.3) and save loading a library for a fairly simple function:

```
function isoStringToDate(s) {
  var d = s.match(/\d+/g);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(d[0],--d[1],d[2],d[3],d[4],d[5],d[6]||0));
}
```

which doesn't care if the Z is there or not. Incidentally, in javascript, an ISO8601 date time string with no timezone [should be treated as UTC](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15).

To get the time value:

```
isoStringToDate('2012-10-11T00:00:00').getTime()
```

or if you want to save a few characters (at the risk of obfuscation):

```
isoStringToDate('2012-10-11T00:00:00')*1
```

but I like the first better.